# Why can we assume $N$ to be a $p$- group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group such that if three distinct primes $p,q$ and $r$  divides $|G|$ then $G$ does not contain any element of order the product of two primes and $G$ is minimal w.r.t this condition. Now if we take $N$ to be any minimal normal subgroup of $G$ then $G/N$ is solvable too.

Let $|G|=p^aq^br^c.m$ such that $p,q,r$ doesnot divide $m$. Let $a,b,c \ge2$.

Now if $pqr \ |\ |G/N|$, then by minimality of $G$, we get an element of order, say $qr$ (WLG), in $G/N$, say $xN\in G/N$ which implies some power of $x$ has order $qr$ in $G$, which is a contradiction to assumption, so all three primes cannot divide $|G/N|$, so supposing (WLG) that $p \ \nmid\ |G/N|$ which implies $p^a\ |\ |N|$.

Here is my **Doubt**-  Why can we now assume $N$ to be a $p$- group? Why cannot the order of $N$ be $p^aq$. I guess it should contradict minimality of $N$ in $G$, but if I consider sylow $q$- subgroup of $N$, which has order $q$, and is unique, then it is normal in $N$, nut it doesnot have to be normal in $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal normal subgroup of any finite group is a direct product of isomorphic simple groups. So if $G$ is solvable then these must be abelian simple groups i.e. cyclic of order $p$ for some prime $p$. So $N$ is a $p$-group.